# Como deshabilitar varios botones que muestran el mismo elemento cuando uno de ellos está clickeado?

Tags: reactjs

Soy nueva en react y quería comentarles el inconveniente que tengo. Estoy haciendo una sección de mi porfolio que se llama proyectos, esta sección muestra una lista de botones con cada proyecto y cada botón muestra la misma card con un resumen del proyecto y un link que te lleva a la página deployada. Lo que quiero lograr hacer es que al darle al botón de proyecto1 se deshabilite el evento onclick de los demás botones que muestran la misma card y al darle click otra vez al boton proyecto1 todos los demás botones se habiliten otra vez. No sé como lograrlo, agradezco mucho la ayuda!

```
const Proyectos = () => {
const [proyectoAMostrar, setProyectoAMostrar] = useState("proyecto1");
const [mostrarBoton, setMostrarBoton] = useState();

 const mostrarProyecto = (proyecto, boton) => {
setProyectoAMostrar(proyecto);
setMostrarBoton(boton);
```

}

```
return (
<Box sx={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", ml: 3 }}>
  <Box>
    <List sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Button
        sx={{
          textTransform: "none",
          fontFamily: "inter",
          fontSize: "18px",
          fontWeight: 600,
          color: "black",
          ":hover": {
            
            color: "#929292"
          },
        }}
        onClick={() => mostrarProyecto("proyecto1", "boton1")} 
        disabled={mostrarBoton !== null && mostrarBoton !== "boton1"}
        
      >
        Portfolio ADA
      </Button>
{proyectoAMostrar === "proyecto1" && (
        <ListItem
          sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly", ml: 6 }}
        >
          <Divider orientation="vertical" variant="middle" flexItem />
          <CardProyectos
            titulo="Portfolio ADA"
            previewProyecto="Este es el primer proyecto del curso de ADA ITW. El enfoque del proyecto es crear un portfolio que sirva para que todo aquel que tenga acceso vea los proyectos logrados en todo el curso. Se creo con HTML y CSS"
            linkProyecto="https://porfoliozuri.netlify.app/"
          />
        </ListItem>
      )}
    </List>
  </Box>

<Box>
    <List sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Button
        sx={{
          textTransform: "none",
          fontFamily: "inter",
          fontSize: "18px",
          fontWeight: 600,
          color: "black",
          ":hover": {
            color: "#929292"
          },
        }}
        onClick={() =>  mostrarProyecto("proyecto2", "boton2")}
        disabled={mostrarBoton !== null && mostrarBoton !== "boton2"}

      >
        Generador de Memes
      </Button>

      {proyectoAMostrar === "proyecto2" && (
        <ListItem sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
          <Divider orientation="vertical" variant="middle" flexItem />
          <CardProyectos
            titulo="Generador de Memes"
            previewProyecto="En este Proyecto realice un editor para generar memes, cree una aplicacion donde se puede manipular el texto y la imagen de un meme. Para lograr esto use JavaScript para modificar dinámicamente su contenido y sus propiedades y completada la edicion se pueda descargar y compartir."
            linkProyecto="https://generadordememesdezuri.netlify.app"
          />
        </ListItem>
      )}
    </List>
  </Box>

<Box>
    <List sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Button
        sx={{
          textTransform: "none",
          fontFamily: "inter",
          fontSize: "18px",
          fontWeight: 600,
          color: "black",
          ":hover": {
            color: "#929292"
          },
        }}
        onClick={() => mostrarProyecto("proyecto3", "boton3")}
        disabled={mostrarBoton !== null && mostrarBoton !== "boton3"}
      >
        Proyecto AhorrADAs
      </Button>
      {proyectoAMostrar === "proyecto3" && (
        <ListItem sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly" }}>
          <Divider orientation="vertical" variant="middle" flexItem />
          <CardProyectos
            titulo="Proyecto AhorrADAs"
            previewProyecto="En este proyecto cree una aplicacion que permite llevar un registro de los gastos realizados y de los ingresos obtenidos. Aplique lo aprendido para estructurar y almacenar la información compleja de la aplicacion y desarrolle funcionalidades que posibilitan manipular y realizar operaciones esenciales a la hora de trabajar con datos. Este Proyecto es un trabajo en grupo"
            linkProyecto="https://generadordememesdezuri.netlify.app"
          />
        </ListItem>
      )}
    </List>
  </Box>


<Box>
    <List sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Button
        sx={{
          textTransform: "none",
          fontFamily: "inter",
          fontSize: "18px",
          fontWeight: 600,
          color: "black",
          ":hover": {
            color: "#929292"
          },
        }}
        onClick={() => mostrarProyecto("proyecto4", "boton4")}
        disabled={mostrarBoton !== null && mostrarBoton !== "boton4"}

      >
        Buscador de Personajes
      </Button>
      {proyectoAMostrar === "proyecto4" &&  (
        <ListItem
          sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly", ml: -3 }}
        >
          <Divider orientation="vertical" variant="middle" flexItem />
          <CardProyectos
            titulo="Buscador de Personajes"
            previewProyecto="En este proyecto cree una aplicacion que permite listar informacion sobre cualquier tema de interes, comunicandome con una API publica. Para esto utilice la API de Rick and Morty, utilizando una API REST con datos reales, haciendo consultas a la misma pasandole distintos parametros que permiten personalizar la búsqueda y mostrar los datos obtenidos como respuesta"
            linkProyecto="https://rickandmorty-browser.netlify.app"
          />
        </ListItem>
      )}
    </List>
  </Box>
<Box>
    <List sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Button
        sx={{
          textTransform: "none",
          fontFamily: "inter",
          fontSize: "18px",
          fontWeight: 600,
          color: "black",
          ":hover": {
            color: "#929292"
          },
        }}
        onClick={() => mostrarProyecto("proyecto5", "boton5")}
        disabled={mostrarBoton !== null && mostrarBoton !== "boton5"}
      >
        Buscador de Peliculas
      </Button>
      {proyectoAMostrar === "proyecto5" &&  (
        <ListItem
          sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly", ml: -1 }}
        >
          <Divider orientation="vertical" variant="middle" flexItem />
          <CardProyectos
            titulo="Buscador de Peliculas"
            previewProyecto="En este proyecto cree una aplicacion con REACT que permite conectarse a una API de películas y mostrar los estrenos, peliculas populares y mejor puntadas."
            linkProyecto="https://buscadordepeliszuri.netlify.app"
          />
        </ListItem>
      )}
    </List>
  </Box>
</Box>
```

);
};

Comment: Puedes deshabilitar el boton en lugar de deshabilitar la propiedad onclick. puedes agregarle al boton la propiedad disabled e igualarla a una variable con la que controles los botones a deshabilitar

Comment: Si no es mucha molestia podrías mostrarme como? Gracias

Comment: No es mucha molestia, pero deberías de poner tu código, porque no voy a hacerte yo todo el trabajo. Una vez vea el código pues te digo como sería. Si no, tendría que hacer un componente entero y sin saber como lo quieres....

Comment: Podrias mostrar ejemplo de tu codigo o dejar link donde se pueda probar, de esa forma es mas facil ayudarte

Comment: Hola @AquilesPerez gracias por responderme, edite la pregunta y añadi el codigo de mi componente asi se entiende mejor, muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Suso ahi edité la pregunta y pude poner el codigo, de antemano gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: He editado mi respuesta con unas modificaciones

Answer (score 0):

Pues podrías hacer una función genérica que diga que componente mostrar y que botón deshabilitar. Te comparto el código de las variables de estado, la función que controla que proyecto mostrar y que botones deshabilitar y el BOX de 1 proyecto, luego tendrías que copiar este box para cada proyecto con el nombre de proyecto en la propiedad onClick del boton correspondiente.

```
 const [proyectoAMostrar, setProyectoAMostrar] = useState("proyecto1");
 const [mostrarBoton, setMostrarBoton] = useState(null);
 function mostrarProyecto(proyecto, boton){
    console.log("hola")
    setProyectoAMostrar(proyecto);

    setMostrarBoton(boton === mostrarBoton ? null : boton);
 }

 <Box>
<List sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
  <Button
    sx={{
      textTransform: "none",
      fontFamily: "inter",
      fontSize: "18px",
      fontWeight: 600,
      color: "black",
      ":hover": {
        
        color: "#929292"
      },
    }}
    onClick={()=>mostrarProyecto("proyecto1", "boton1")}
    disabled={mostrarBoton !== null && mostrarBoton !== "boton1")
  >
    Portfolio ADA
  </Button>


  {proyectoAMostrar === "proyecto1" && (
    <ListItem
      sx={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-evenly", ml: 6 }}
    >
      <Divider orientation="vertical" variant="middle" flexItem />
      <CardProyectos
        titulo="Portfolio ADA"
        previewProyecto="Este es el primer proyecto del curso de ADA ITW. El enfoque del proyecto es crear un portfolio que sirva para que todo aquel que tenga acceso vea los proyectos logrados en todo el curso. Se creo con HTML y CSS"
        linkProyecto="https://porfoliozuri.netlify.app/"
      />
    </ListItem>
  )}
</List>
</Box>
```

Si tienes algun problema avisa....

Comment: Hola @Suso tengo un problema con el codigo respecto a la solucion que me ofreciste, segui tu sugerencia de crear las dos variables de estado para poder manipular los botones segun lo que quiero que se muestre o no pero ahora tengo inhabilitado todos los botones. editare la pregunta de vuelta con el nuevo codigo asi puedo explicarme mejor, muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola @Suso ahi edite la pregunta y comparti el codigo! gracias por ayudarme!

Comment: Te falta la funcion proyecto a mostrar que es la que modifica las variables de estado

Comment: Hola @Suso! disculpa que no copie la funcion pero ahi edite de vuelta la pregunta, la funcion esta añadida a mi codigo pero aun asi me da el mismo problema

Comment: Ya he editado la respuesta con unos pequeños retoques. la he probado y funciona. Había que cambiar el valor inicial de mostrarboton y la condición de si se pulsa el mismo boton desbloquee todos

Comment: muchas gracias, me ayudaste un montón!

Comment: Hola @Suso disculpa la molestia, pero estoy intentando hacer el responsive de este componente y me genera muchos problemas ver en donde estoy fallando, estoy haciendolo con Material UI. Como sabes viste que del lado lateral izquierdo se encuentran los botones y luego del lado lateral derecho se encuentra la card. No encuentro la manera de colocar la card debajo en modo responsive, no se que estoy haciendo mal, podrias darme una mano? muchas gracias

Comment: pues así a bote pronto, yo al elemento list y al listitem le pondría en el atributo classname la misma clase(el nombre que quieras para distinguirlos del resto) y luego controlaria con css la horientación. le pondría normal display:flex y flex-direction: row y crearía un media-query con maximo de pixeles los que tu quieras para que cambie de horientación vertical a horizontal y añadiría esa clase al media query con un flex-direction column